Show that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2x+1+e^{-x}}{\cos^2 x+1+e^{-x}}$ does not exist
How to show that the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2x+1+e^{-x}}{\cos^2 x+1+e^{-x}}
$$
does not exist?
My idea is to write
$$
\frac{\sin^2x+1+e^{-x}}{\cos^2 x+1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{-x}(1+e^x\sin^2 x+e^x)}{e^{-x}(1+e^x\cos^2 x+e^x)}=\frac{1+e^x\sin^2 x+e^x}{1+e^x\cos^2 x+e^x}
$$

You could attempt an "approximated" argument, i.e., for very large $x$, $e^{-x} ≈ 0$, so it becomes a negligible term. Thus, we are ideally dealing with:
$$\lim_{x\to ∞}\dfrac{\sin^2(x) + 1}{\cos^2(x) + 1}$$
Then, you may show that:
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sin^2(x) + 1}{\cos^2(x) + 1}$$
is an oscillating function with a period of $π$. Therefore, the limit does not exist. $\blacksquare$
Don't know if this would be a strong argument though...

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2 n\pi +1+e^{-n\pi}}{\cos^2 n\pi+1+e^{-n\pi}}=\frac 1  2$ and $\lim_{n\,\, \text {odd}, n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2 n(\pi/2) +1+e^{-n(\pi/2)}}{\cos^2 n(\pi/2)+1+e^{-n(\pi/2)}}= 2$.
